# Include custom post types in categories widget

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, widgets

So I got a fairly simple setup, one CPT with the default `category` and `post_tag` as taxonomies.

Say I have 1 post and 1 CPT entry assigned to the same category. I need this to be reflected inside the category widget as well.

I've managed to display both of them on the category page via the `request` filter so the links generated by the widget work.

The problem is that if the post didn't exist, the widget would not generate a link for the category (considering it empty).

Also, the item count is incorrect, 1 instead of 2.

#### Digging through the widget code, this is what's causing the problems:

```
wp_list_categories(apply_filters('widget_categories_args', $cat_args));
```

So I can alter the arguments via the filter but `wp_list_categories()` doesn't have an argument for what post type it should use.

#### I've seen someone else encounter the problem before:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-types-and-category-widget - no luck

http://themehybrid.com/support/topic/custom-post-types-and-category-widget - same guy, can't read Justin's responses but I assume no luck again. he filed a ticket at the end which got closed

#### Thoughts on the solution

I'd really like to not copy/paste the default widget code and create a new one but solve this using a filter somehow.

That being said, would a custom walker help with this? Any ideas?

As a sidenote, I solved a similar issue with the Archives widget using this:

```
/*
* Add CPTs to wp_get_archives()
* http://bajada.net/2010/07/15/adding-custom-post-types-to-wp_get_archives
*/
function ucc_getarchives_where_filter( $where , $r ) {
    $args = array( 'public' => true , '_builtin' => false );
    $output = 'names'; $operator = 'and';

    $post_types = get_post_types( $args , $output , $operator );
    $post_types = array_merge( $post_types , array( 'post' ) ); $post_types = "'" . implode( "' , '" , $post_types ) . "'";

    return str_replace( "post_type = 'post'" , "post_type IN ( $post_types )" , $where );
}
add_filter( 'getarchives_where' , 'ucc_getarchives_where_filter' , 10 , 2 );
```

Cheers!

Comment: This is one of those situations where hacking your way trough filters to change the behavior of some widget is stupid. Just create your own widget - you'll write less, more readable and faster code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an 'actor' cpt and it seems to automatically get added to the query:

```
SELECT object_id, term_taxonomy_id
FROM wp_term_relationships INNER JOIN wp_posts ON object_id = ID 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (38,40,30,11,32,34,29,39,35,9,31,19,33,37,42,41,27,25,36,1,26) 
AND post_type IN ('post', 'actor')
AND post_status = 'publish'

Call from: require, require_once, include, get_sidebar, get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require, dynamic_sidebar, call_user_func_array, WP_Widget->display_callback, WP_Widget_Categories->widget, wp_list_categories, get_categories, get_terms, _pad_term_counts
```

(Using the [Debug Queries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-queries/) plugin)

And this is the CPT definition:

```
register_post_type('actor', array(
  'public' => true,
  'labels' => $labels,
  'has_archive' => 'actors',
  'taxonomies' => array( 'category' )
));
```

Comment: Turns out you are right, it works but only on 3.3-aortic-dissection, not on 3.2.1 yet. :)

Comment: Will this work in 3.9?  My CPT aren't automatically showing in the query.